# Using Infinite Scroll with AJAX and Mustache render

Tags: ajax, infinite-scroll, mustache

I have a jsp page in which I am loading the posts using AJAX which responds in JSON data. The HTML is rendered using the Mustache renderer. The question is how can I use this Infinite Scroll using this scenario. I have read that jQuery load() method can be used but I am not able to get it work. If anybody guide me that will be helpful.

```
var data = "";
        $.getJSON("/ajax?command=getposts", function(returnedData){            
            console.log("bar"+returnedData);
            var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(returnedData));
            //alert(JSON.stringify(returnedData));
            console.log(data);
            $.get('temp.html', function(templates)
            {
                var tpl = $(templates).filter('#content').html();
                //console.log(data);
                var html = Mustache.to_html(tpl, returnedData);
                $('#posts').html(html);
                $('#posts').imagesLoaded(function() {

                    $('#posts').freetile({
                        animate: true,
                        elementDelay: 30
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

This is the Jquery code that I use to load the posts in the container. I want to implement the Infinite Scroll which will call this  method everytime the user scrolls.